# View on View not visible on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

[image]I'm developing an app where I have to show details of a post. Now, when clicked and running iOS8 and above.. The view is displayed but when running on iOS7, it is masked by the image view over it.
In the image, The Transparent view showing the price is maksed by the image on iOS7.
Please Help!!

Comment: post relevant codes also

Comment: It is done directly on xibs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

select uiimageview and set clipsubviews checked from property window like this http://prntscr.com/7z4usj

Answer (score 0):

Show a bit of your code.

I was so with cells and helped me:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Maybe try :

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```